# Can Somebody Help me out with this SOAP Error description

Tags: vb.net, iis, soap, wsdl, webserver

```
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 10.0
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2021-01-27 10:55:01
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken

2021-01-27 10:55:02 192.168.1.1 POST /Honeywell/WebServices/WebDataAccess.asp +SOAP+ERROR:+SoapServer.SoapInvoke+failed.+WSDLOperation:Executing+method+ReadRequest+failed+HRESULT=0x80020009 80 PCNGATE\BizTalk 192.168.1.15 - - 500 0 0 296
```

Question:
Here we are sending a SOAP message from a SOAP client to a Webserver requesting for some data.The name of  the soap method we call on the web server is "Readrequest" this method returns a good value most of the time but sometimes we get the error as shown above with server error code 500 and HResult 0x80020009 .Can it be because we are bulk requesting everything at once?

Comment: The error ties too closely to the web app itself (status code 500 is web app internal error), so you can only debug the web app (like `WebDataAccess.asp` page and related pages), or consult its original developers. No one else can help much.

Comment: How does your Readrequest method work? Can you show me the relevant code?

Comment: --This is the ReadRequest Method in the .wsdl---
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<qwds xmlns="">
  <ReadRequest>
    <RequestBase ReturnItemTime="true" ReturnItemName="true" ReturnItemPath="true" />
    <ItemList>
      <Item ItemName="Value" >
        <ItemRequestSpec ItemPath="Gate.example.tag" />
      </Item>
    </ItemList>
  </ReadRequest>
</qwds>

Comment: The actual implementation of the Method in the WebServer I do not know. Since I am the SOAP client , And the readrequests worked properly for the past 2years and then we upgraded the webserver and now it gives that error every once in a while

Comment: Can you be sure when this error will occur? Does this happen when running locally?

Comment: The Webserver is Hosted on the IIS on a physical server. And the SOAP client sending the readrequest is another server in the same network

Comment: Have you got other error messages? such as error code.

Comment: +SOAP+ERROR:+SoapServer.SoapInvoke+failed.+WSDLOperation:Executing+method+ReadRequest+failed+HRESULT=0x80020009

Comment: This error does not seem to be of great help in solving the problem. Have you checked whether there are related error messages in your Event Viewer?